# Change Slider height with handler Android. MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, .net-maui

I am trying to change the slider's Height/Thickness in order to have a less ankward touch interaction on Android.

I am using a [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize).

This is what I tried :

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SliderHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            // Update slider thickness
            handler.PlatformView.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100);
            handler.PlatformView.MinHeight = 100;
            handler.PlatformView.SetMinimumHeight(100);
#endif
        });
    }
}
```

None of these works.
I am sure that the mapper is registering correctly because I tried some more trivial case successfully :

```cs
handler.PlatformView.Min = 1;
handler.PlatformView.Max = 100;
handler.PlatformView.Progress = 50; // Set slider progress to 50%
```

How can I change the slider trackbar and thumb interaction height ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is just the case as you said.

And I have created a new issue about this problem, you can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10259 .

Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

Best Regards.

Comment: Hi @Pierre Said, if my reply is useful for this problem, could you please mark it as answered so that  it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)